# PayPal API - Is it possible to get withdrawal information?

Tags: api, paypal

I see in the GetTransactionDetails documentation it says:

**> You cannot obtain details of bank transfer withdrawals, for example.**

Is there another way to get these transaction details?

Comment: I suggest asking PayPal support

Answer (score 0):

All the information I needed was in the data returned from my initial TransactionSearch.